# Which data types should a client model use for offline sync with the Azure mobile apps SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using the offline-sync stuff in Azure's mobile app services SDK.

I'm aware that there have been various changes recently in the SDK. I want to define client models according to the latest spec, but not sure which types to use.

These are the offline-sync metadata properties, typically seen in **most** examples/tutorials:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public string Id { get; set; }

[Version]
public string Version { get; set; }

[CreatedAt]
public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

[UpdatedAt]
public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

[Deleted]
public bool Deleted { get; set; }
```

But some [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#optimisticconcurrency) and [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231551/3959480), as well as various official (too many!) [samples/quickstarts on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/blob/master/TodoListXamarinForms/ToDoAzure/ToDoAzure/Models/ToDoItem.cs), use a combination of types.

So I've seen this too in various places:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public Guid Id { get; set; }              // Guid is used here, not string

[Version]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "version")]  // Needed? I assume the attribute is enough
public byte[] Version { get; set; }       // byte[] is used here, not string
```

Under the covers everything is done via REST calls, and thus strings. So I assume the client SDK performs various type conversions.

*But I don't want my app to bomb inexplicably at some point in the future, when things change. So which officially supported types should I be using?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client SDK requires only a string Id field (that should be named "Id", unless you want to jump through a bunch of hoops). The value of the string can be any unique string. The Server SDKs use a string-converted GUID by default. When using offline sync, the client SDK also generates a string GUID unless an ID is specified. When using the **online** `IMobileServiceTable` APIs, the client lets the server generate the ID.

The rest of the fields are optional and should either have the types you listed, or be convertible to them.

Here's your data model, with comments on the various fields:

```
// required, should be called Id, *must* be of type string when using offline sync
// When not using offline sync, should be string-convertible.
// When using offline sync, the client SDK uses a new string-converted GUID for this, unless 
// an ID is specified.
// When using offline sync, Ids are not mutable, so use something that can be client generated
public string Id { get; set; }

// optional. Using a Version field opts you into optimistic concurrency, where 
// the server will reject updates that are done against an older version
// of an object. This means you need a conflict handler.
// To use a client-wins policy, remove this property from your client object
[Version]
public string Version { get; set; }

// optional. Cannot be set on the client, will be sent from the server
[CreatedAt]
public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

// optional. Cannot be set on the client, will be sent from the server
[UpdatedAt]
public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

// should generally not be used in the client object at all. This field tracks 
// which objects have been deleted so that they are automatically purged
// from the client's offline sync store
[Deleted]
public bool Deleted { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is a great reference... all the different issues in one place... thank you!

Comment: About the `Id` though - according to a comment above, I can use `Guid` (rather than `string`). And for `Version` I'd like to use `byte[]` (rather than  `string`). Seems more natural to me for my data model, but, am I asking for trouble by doing that?

Comment: Yes, because you'd be requiring that the string would be convertible to a GUID, which the server does not require. @adrian-hall's actually meant you should use a string representation of a GUID, not an actual GUID type.

Comment: @hbob I added some more details about client ID generation to the answer.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, I'm trying to understand... but if I use a `Guid` for my client-side model's PK, and under the hood requests are sent via REST (i.e. as strings), then surely the .NET runtime would convert my Guid to a string anyway and then sent a sync request? I suppose the problem you are highlighting is that a response would be SENT BACK as a `string`, and the SDK would not know how to convert it to a `Guid`?

Comment: Also, I should have split my above comment into two, sorry... What about my idea of a `byte[]` type for version. Is that safe, or does it suffer the same problem (because some of the docs do this, and some do that).

Comment: @hbob That's right, the response can be sent back as an arbitrary string (or new records could be created by updating the database directly), and that string might not be convertible to a GUID. Also, if you're using offline sync with the default local store implementation, I believe a GUID for ID might fail or cause subtle bugs. For Version, it's possible byte[] would work, but string is safer. You shouldn't ever need to manipulate it as a byte array on the client.

Comment: `version`: I never thought of that, you're right of course - I'll never manipulate it. It's an weird SDK implementation detail that is unfortunately surfaced and causes confusion. [The official client-side doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#optimisticconcurrency) is the culprit! :-)

Answer (score -1):

<s>Looks like you can use almost anything for the `id` column, as long as it's unique. [Even an email address!](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#inserting) (feels like NoSQL...) I've decided on a Guid, so all entities are consistent upon creation (no need to wait for server's response).</s>

I've decided upon a byte array for the `version` column, as it seems to return exactly that from the server.

**EDIT:** This is quite wrong. See comment below and new accepted answer above.

Comment: Technically, not true.  Your Id field MUST be unique among ALL clients - there must be NO RISK of two clients referencing two different objects with the same ID.  A Guid is a good choice.

Comment: Aaah, yes that makes sense. Two users may decide to use the same email address! Thanks for the clarification. I'm using a Guid (instead of a string) as you recommended.